# Why isn't my ListView ItemClick event being triggered?

Tags: xamarin.android

**Why doesn't my ItemClick event trigger?**

```
_specialtyListView.ItemClick += (s, e) => _viewModel.Specialty = (string)_specialtyListView.Adapter.GetItem((int)e.Id);
```

> NOTE:
>
> 1. The listview is populated.
> 2. Items receive focus.

However, I just cannot get the itemclick event to trigger.

**I have the following initialization code for my ListView:**

```
_specialtyListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.SpecialtyListView);
_specialtyListView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;
_viewModel.LoadSpecialties();
_specialtyListView.Adapter = new SpecialtiesAdapter(this, new List<string>(_viewModel.Specialties));
_specialtyListView.ItemClick += (s, e) => _viewModel.Specialty = (string)_specialtyListView.Adapter.GetItem((int)e.Id);
```

**I then have the following ListViewItem layout:**

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/SpecialtyListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="#CCCCCC"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp" />
```

**Here's the Layout for my ListItem:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProviderSpecialty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you switch to RecyclerView as it is has better memory handling; you can make updates to single items instead of being forced to update them all.

Anyways, I can't reproduce your issue locally. I did the following:

```
var listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listview);
listView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;
listView.ItemClick += (s, e) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Clicked {e.Position}");
};

var items = new string[] { "Havarti", "Brie", "Cheddar", "Muenster", "Swiss" };
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
listView.Adapter = adapter;
```

I used the exact same layout as you posted. The `ItemClick` handler is hit consistently.

Comment: The ArrayAdapter works for what I need. Still not sure why my custom adapter did not work...

Comment: If you can post your custom Adapter I can help you debug that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug where the breakpoint will NOT be triggered when the code is NOT wrapped in between braces:

```
listview.ItemClick += (s, e) => selectedItem = listview.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString();
```

To observe the breakpoint, I had to format the code as the following:

```
listview.ItemClick += (s, e) =>
    {
        selectedItem = listview.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString();
    };
```

Comment: That is not a bug. Your breakpoint is set for the assignment of the eventhandler in that case and not the body of the eventhandler.

Comment: In Visual Studio, you can set a breakpoint in line where the handler itself can receive a breakpoint. Hence, the entire line is not highlighted brown. Just the handler code is highlighted brown. That's not a bug?